# How to move the slider at specific position in Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I have a slider whose minimum range is 0 and maximum range is 17; if I want to move the slider to specific position say, @10, how can I do it?

I am using offset, but it is not moving to a specific position. Below is the code I have used; this is working fine, but it is not moving the slider to the desired expected position.

```
IWebElement slider = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='mcl-range__nutrition.dietaryFiber']"));
int slidersizewidth = slider.Size.Width;//640
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.ClickAndHold(slider);
action.MoveByOffset(40, 0).Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Try to do it using for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see there's already a good answer for this but I'd just like to add my explicit solution in case it helps anyone.

**This solution allows you to explicitly say what amount you want any slider to be instead of passing in pixel values or manually calculating it for each slider.**

So quite simply to move the slider we need to call something like.

```
IWebElement Slider = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*[@id='abc']"))
Actions SliderAction = new Actions(driver);
SliderAction.ClickAndHold(Slider)
    .MoveByOffset((-(int)Slider.Size.Width / 2), 0)
    .MoveByOffset(Pixels, 0).Release().Perform();
```

The problem with this is here we tell the driver how many **pixels** to move the slider instead of the actual **amount** that we want to move it to.

---

So in order to convert the **amount** we want to set the slider to, to the **pixels** this would require we can use the following equation expressed through code.

```
public static int GetPixelsToMove(IWebElement Slider, decimal Amount, decimal SliderMax, decimal SliderMin)
    {
        int pixels = 0;
        decimal tempPixels = Slider.Size.Width;
        tempPixels = tempPixels / (SliderMax - SliderMin);
        tempPixels = tempPixels * (Amount - SliderMin);
        pixels = Convert.ToInt32(tempPixels);
        return pixels;
    }
```

- Where SliderMax and SliderMin are the maximum and minimum **amounts** the slider can be set to
- Amount is the amount value we want to set the slider to
- Width is how wide the slider is in pixels
- And Pixels is the calculated output value in **pixels** which is how far we will have to move the slider

---

For example:

If I had a slider to represent a range of days which was 100 pixels wide, had a minimum value of 2 days, a maximum value of 18 days, and we wanted to set it to be 7 days, we'd use a method like this.

```
IWebElement Slider = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*[@id='abc']"))
int PixelsToMove = GetPixelsToMove(Slider, 7, 18, 2)
Actions SliderAction = new Actions(driver);
SliderAction.ClickAndHold(Slider)
    .MoveByOffset((-(int)Slider.Size.Width / 2),0)
    .MoveByOffset(PixelsToMove, 0).Release().Perform();
```

And this would set the slider to be 7 days.

Full disclosure, this was taken from my repo [here](https://github.com/JamesMatchett/Selenium-Move-Sliders-Library/) where it's already packaged as a class library for C# if you want to save some time with some additional methods to help automation.

Answer (score 5):

Try with below simple Examples:

Ex 1:

```
    WebElement slider = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='mcl-range__nutrition.dietaryFiber']")); 

    Actions action= new Actions(driver);
    action.clickAndHold(Slider);
    action.moveByOffset(40,0);
    action.release().build();
```

Ex 2:

```
   int x=10;
   WebElement slider = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='mcl-range__nutrition.dietaryFiber']"));
   int width = slider.getSize().getWidth();
   Actions act= new Actions(driver);
   act.moveToElement(slider, ((width*x)/100), 0).click();
   act.build().perform();
```

Ex 3: Using For Loop

```
    WebElement slider = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='mcl-range__nutrition.dietaryFiber']")); 

    Actions action= new Actions(driver);
    action.click(slider).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        action.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }


NOTE: Change arrow RIGHT/LEFT/UP/DOWN as per your condition.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that calculating the offset by pixels was off due to rounding from float to int, so the solution I found was to first move the slider to the beginning and then move the arrow key in a loop. Each arrow key move to the right is one unit of the slider.

```
Actions action = new Actions(_driver);

var width = slider.Size.Width;
//the moment you issue a click Selenium clicks in the center of the slider
//therefore to move slider to beginning we need to move left half of the slider's length
action.ClickAndHold(slider).MoveByOffset(-(int)(width / 2), 0).Perform();
int increment = 50;
for (int i = 0; i < increment ; i++)
{
   action.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowRight);
}
action.Perform();
```